# Joining CAT x cable with soldered joins - will it affect ADSL?

Tags: networking, cable, adsl

I live in a rural area. I always thought my 1.5 Mbps down speed was part of life. After a technician visit, he fixed some phone cable joins in my 35yo house and increased my speed to 5.5 Mbps. His machine showed that there are still 1 or 2 joins that he couldn't access to repair. That machine also showed 9 Mbps at exterior ADSL splitter he installed.

His advice to me (outside the scope of his telco tech visit) was to run some CAT 5e or 6 cable from that splitter to my modem's phone point. I need about 50m. And I have several 10m lengths.

My question is this: Given that the guy's machine detected joins based on different metals (different wires) being joined together and given that those joins cost me about 30% of my potential speed, would soldering the same type of cable (my 10m lengths) be like different cables, or would I be making one cable in terms of the sensitivity of the ADSL signal?

Comment: Yes, it will affect your speed. Just buy a 50m cable.

Comment: Your current problem is bad wiring, likely configured in a very similar way, of that of your proposed way.  Just spend the [$16.06](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=2379) and just buy a 100 foot cable.

Comment: You're telling me what I need to hear...

Comment: @Ramhound While being your opinion on the fact, I do need to point out that 100ft are only ca. 33m, which might not be enough!

Comment: @EugenRieck Yeah, alright so 200 feet for $32.12 would just need to find a different supplier

Comment: @Ramhound Didn't want to be pedantic, just make sure the OP gets wat he needs. You are ofcourse right, that recabling is by far the best option.